# If on excel returns false while dealing with more than one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new learner of Microsoft Excel, currently using Microsoft Excel 2007.
I'd learned the "if" formula :

```
=if(logical_test;[value_if_true];[value_if_false])
```

so I created an if statement like this :

```
=if(5+5=10;A1="Right answer";A2="Wrong Answer")
```

and it returned false, what's wrong?
if I create something like this :

```
=if(5+5=10;A1="Right answer";A1="Wrong Answer")
```

it'll return "Right answer" in the targeted cell

Comment: Actually, you cannot make a formula modify the value in a cell other than the one you are putting the formula in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your concept of formulas: The result of one formula is always stored/displayed in the  cell that the formula is written.

So in your case, you actually need to modify your formula like this

```
=IF(5+5=10;"Right answer";"Wrong answer")
```

and place it either in A1 or A2.

Answer (score 0):

You also should use commas between each argument rather than a semicolon.

```
=IF(5+5=10, "Right answer", "Wrong answer")
```

Comment: This is locale-dependent. Some locales use semicolons.

Comment: Thanks GSerg. Most standard excel installs use commas rather than semicolons as the seperator. Point taken.